# How to maintain sequence of multiple targets in a makefile with -j option

Tags: makefile

I have a script which generates C++ files. First I want to generate these files.
Then compile them in a library.
I want to do this in a single Makefile.

```
TARGETS = GEN_FILE LIBNAME

GEN_FILE: input
  BINARYTOGEN input

OBJ =(GENERATED_FILES:.cpp-.o)

LIBNAME: $(OBJ)
    cc $(OBJ)
```

How can I make sure target GEN_FILE always run before LIBNAME in a parallel environment when used –j option.

One way is .NOTPARALLEL.

```
 .generated_marker: a.gen b.gen
   touch a.cpp
   touch b.cpp
   touch $@

 SRCS = a.cpp b.cpp

$(SRCS): .generated_marker

OBJ = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

OUT = ./libutils.a

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUT)

 .SUFFIXES: .cpp

 LIBS = -L…

  INCLUDES = -I…..

 .cpp.o:
         gcc $(INCLUDES) -g -c $< -o $@

  $(OUT): $(OBJ)
         ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)
```

Comment: `How can I make sure target GEN_FILE always run before LIBNAME` - Just make `LIBNAME` dependent from `GEN_FILE`: add string `LIBNAME: GEN_FILE` into your makefile.

Comment: I did that. But with make -j option, it does not seem to work

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Could you provide example, when it doesn't work? For visualize execution order, you could add print-like receipts (e.g., `echo $@`) to both targets (`GEN_FILE` and `LIBNAME`).

Answer (score 0):

If your generator processes single source file and generates single output file, it is simple - just add pattern rule, e.g.:

```
all: a.out

%.c: %.gen
    cp $< $@

SRCS:=a.c b.c

a.out: $(SRCS)
    gcc $^
```

(I use `cp` for simplicity, it should be your actual generator, e.g. flex, bison, lemon, .....)

It is possible your generator produces a lot of files at once (or even all of them), then you probably need to create a flag file which timestamp will indicate latest re-generation, e.g.:

```
all: a.out

.generated_marker: a.gen b.gen
    touch a.c
    touch b.c
    touch $@

SRCS:=a.c b.c

$(OBJS):=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(OBJS): .generated_marker

a.out: $(OBJS)
    gcc $^
```

Comment: I don't have the names of the generated source files. a.c b.c are not known till they are generated. I can get source name only by ls *.c

Comment: It doesn't change a thing. `touch` is an example, replace with your generator.

Comment: On the second thought, it does. Where did you intended to get `GENERATED_FILES` then?

Comment: My generator takes an input xml file and generates multiple cpp files. Once generator is run, i can try doing  $(wildcard $(OUTPUT_DIR/*.cpp)

Comment: How exactly, with `eval`? I don't think you can add dependencies like that. It probably can be achieved with extra phony target, but this method just asks for problems. Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: Also in your eg. i am getting error "no rule to make target a.gen needed by .generated_marker"

Comment: It should depend on files used by your generator.

Comment: .generated_marker:  a.gen b.gen
        touch a.cpp
        touch b.cpp
        touch $@

SRCS = a.cpp b.cpp

$(SRCS): .generated_marker

OBJ = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

OUT = ./libutils.a

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUT)

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

LIBS = -L…

INCLUDES = -I…..

.cpp.o:
        gcc $(INCLUDES) -g -c $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
        ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJ)

Comment: When I "make –j4 all" first start (after clean), it works fine.
Now I edit  a.gen. and do make –j4 all , only following commands are executed. Library is  not relinked. Doing make –j4 second time relinks library. Whereas doing only make all links library too.
        touch a.cpp
        touch b.cpp
        touch $@

Comment: keltar, I have pasted your modified makefile in the main question section. Sorry for the bad formatting in comment section, but I cannot correct it.

Comment: @chan sorry you're correct, `$(OBJ)` should depend on generator flag, not `$(SRCS)`. I've made an edit, check it out. Works as expected for me.

Comment: Looks better. Thanks